# Unable to route to different templates in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here, I am unable to route, i have files in the same folder as '`consumpt.html`'
'`fulfillment.html`'

```
<html>
    <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
              <script src="assets/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap-3.3.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myapp">

                            <a  href="#/">Fulfill</a>
                            <a  href="#/consumpt">Consumpt</a>

      <div class='col-xs-12 rmpm' style='height:auto;' ng-controller="viewForNavigation">
                    <div ng-view></div>
                </div>
    <script>
      angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']).config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/consumpt', {
                controller: 'viewForNavigation',
                templateUrl: 'consumpt.html'
            });

            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                controller: 'viewForNavigation',
                templateUrl: 'fulfillment.html'
            })
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you registered your controllers with Angular? Also, you shouldn't need `ng-controller` in the view if you are putting it in the route definition.

Comment: How to register controller in above scenario.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any script tags which would load your controllers (they all look like 3rd-party dependencies). It looks like you still have to register your controllers with Angular:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller("viewForNavigation", ["dep1", "dep2", function(dep1, dep2) {
    // Your controller code
}])
```

Also, you shouldn't need `ng-controller` in the view if you are putting it in the `controller` property of a route.

Comment: I am trying to route.

Comment: @ManzerAhmad I understand, but I don't see any script tags which would load files that register your controllers with Angular. All of your script tags look like they are for 3rd-party dependencies. Also, I don't think you need the `ng-controller` in the view anymore, unless you really do need 2 instances of the `viewForNavigation` controller.